# programming kindle fire style coverflow gallery in flash or jquery

Tags: jquery, flash, actionscript-3, kindle, kindle-fire

I'm trying to duplicate the style of coverflow gallery used on the home screen of the kindle fire, where books slide across the shelf and flip at the end. Any idea of where I might be able to find some initial source to work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into [jQuery UI CoverFlow 2.0](http://addyosmani.com/blog/jqueryuicoverflow/)

Or [JavaScript CoverFlow 2.0 (jCoverFlow)](http://jcoverflow.sourceforge.net/)

You might have to look into modifying some mouse-over type of events appropriately for touch, but everything else would be built for you.